# how to use javascript to get value from json

Tags: javascript, json

i need to get the value of the following json with javascript:

```
var json = JSON.parse(data); //{"rows":[{"id": 224,"data": ["$988.60"]}]}

console.log(json.rows[1].data); //throws an error.
```

Comment: `console.log(json.rows[0].data[0]);`

Comment: Arrays start at an index of `0`.

Comment: Be careful with your names - "JSON" is a data format, not the type of an object. So `var someFoo` or something like that makes sense, but if you're going to name a variable `json`, it should be a string. For example, `var json = JSON.stringify({a:1});`

Comment: @JoeEnos I think that OP has worse problems than misleading variable names.

Comment: @Gothdo Just a pet peeve of mine - so many people mistake javascript object literals for JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In javascript `arrays` has `0` based index. If you want to access the first element then you have to target the index `0` not `1`. If you try to access an index that is greater than of array's `length` then that will return `undefined`. So accessing a `property` from `undefined` will throw an error like

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'something' of undefined

Here in your case you have to access your required data by,

```
console.log(json.rows[0].data[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

"rows" is an array of 1 element, indexed from 0. So all you need is rows[0].